# Taking Limits of 2 function

Tags: limits, derivatives

I am taking the log of both numerator and denominator and then trying to find out the limits through L'Hospital's Rule. I am taking log because it makes it easier to differentiate the 2 functions. But I am not sure if this is a valid way to solve the problem. Can anyone clarify this?

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\log_2 f(n)}{\log_2 g(n)}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{3^n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \Big( \frac23 \Big)^n = 0$$ but
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log_2(2^n)}{\log_2(3^n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n }{n \log_2 3} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\log_23} = \frac{1}{\log_23}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a slight mistake in your part. Let us take,
$$y=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f\left(n\right)}{g\left(n\right)}$$
Then, if we take log on both sides, we'll get,
$$\log{y}=\log\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f\left(n\right)}{g\left(n\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\log\frac{f\left(n\right)}{g\left(n\right)}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\log{f\left(n\right)}-\log{g\left(n\right)}\right)$$